# A quotient by a characteristic subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a polycyclic by finit group the it exists a subgroup A normal with $G/A$ is finit and it's order is equal to m
I want the proof of the following

i know that $G^{m}$ is a characteristic subgroup (m is a natural number) 
why $G/G^{m}$ is periodic ?

Comment: By periodic do you mean all elements have finite order? Then clearly this is not the case.

Comment: not necessarily they have a finite order we can take as an example $\G^m$

Comment: Then what do you mean by periodic?

Comment: I mean that every elements of the quotient have a finite order but not every element of G

Comment: Well yes, then clearly this is not the case because the trivial subgroup is characteristic. Or the commutator subgroup of a free group of rank $2$.

Comment: what i wanted to say is that i know that $G^{m}$ is characteristic and $G/G^{m}$ is periodic but i want the proof

Comment: Then please update the question to reflect this. For that particular question, it is basically just a matter of applying the definitions.

Comment: What does $G^m$ mean here? I ask because $\{g^m : g \in G\}$ is not a subgroup in general.

Comment: yes i ve forgotten to say that G is polycyclic bay finit i'll update the question

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I assume it means subgroup generated by $m$'th powers.

Comment: There is no need for the whole polycyclic addition. It ought to be easy to directly show that $G/G^m$ is periodic.

Comment: but i couldn't proof it

Comment: Hint: Show that in fact $x^m = 1$ for all $x$ in the quotient.

Comment: yes it's done it's so easy i didn't pay attention thnks